# javascript + php Uncaught syntaxerror unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, class

I have problem with javascript.

I want to add html code to div :

```
modalTag.find("#testowe").text("<?php echo strip_tags($this->mail['content']); ?>");
```

On $this->mail['content']; I have something like this :

```
<div class="WordSection1">
    <p class="MsoNormal">To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. <p></p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
</div>
```

But I have error Uncaught syntaxerror unexpected identifier

Can u help me?

Sorry for my english.

```
            $("#clientModal").remove();
        var modalTag = $("<div id='clientModal'></div>");
        modalTag.bind("beforeOpenClientWindow", function() {
            modalTag.find("#email").val("<?php echo $this->mail['sender_email'] ?>");
            modalTag.find("#client_type").val(clientType);
            modalTag.find("#sName").append('<?php echo $this->mail['sender_name'].' ('.$this->mail['sender_email'].')'; ?>');
            modalTag.find("#subject").append('<?php echo $this->mail['subject'];?>');
            modalTag.find("#testowe").text("<?php var_dump(strip_tags($this->mail['content'])); ?>");
        });
        openClientModal("Dodaj nowego " + clientString, modalTag, isSupplier);
    }
```

EDIT : 
If I add this `modalTag.find("#testowe").html("<?php var_dump($this->mail['content']); ?>");` I have error : " Unexpected string"
In $this->mail['content'] I have :

```
<div class="WordSection1">
<p class="MsoNormal">To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. To jest długa wiadomośc. <p></p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><p> </p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you do a <?php var_dump(strip_tags($this->mail['content'])); ?> and post the result here ?

Comment: If I do this I get this same error

Comment: are you sure the error is related to this line ? can you do a die() before and then after the var_dump to see if the error appears before or after this line ?

Comment: Yes, If I add die(); This after <?php var_dump(strip_tags($this->mail['content'])); ?>  I didn't get error, but If I delete die(); Error are showing

Comment: can you show us the entire code ?

Comment: I added my code to my question.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
modalTag.find("#testowe").html('<?php echo strip_tags($this->mail['content']); ?>');
```

Comment: I solved my problem with `modalTag.find("#testowe").html('<?php echo json_encode($this->mail['content']); ?>');`